# Can you cover $\mathbb R$ with countably many smol sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, recreational-mathematics

Say a set $X\subset\mathbb R$ is *smol* if one can't cover $\mathbb R$ with countably many translates of $X$.

So, for example, null-measure sets are smol. I guess sets of positive measure are not, but I have not been able to prove it yet. Non-measurable sets are a mystery.

I wonder: can you cover $\mathbb R$ with countably many smol sets?

This question came as an effort to find a maximal family $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ such that any countable union over $\mathcal F$ is not $\mathbb R$. This would give a rough notion of measure (only telling if a set is big or small) to every subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. By Baire category theorem, sets of first category are smol. And $\mathbb R$ can be decomposed as a disjiont union of a measure $0$ set and a set of first category ([Theorem 1.6](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9339-9) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494705/intuition-of-decomposition-of-mathbbr-into-disjoint-union-of-first-category)). This is exactly the point of the 1st chapter of Measure and Category: There is no uniform notion of being "small".

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question. I am explaining how to find non-smol sets, but I don't know about the question of whether or not you can cover $\Bbb R$ with smols. This just partially addresses the Op's "guess".

If $X$ contains a set of positive measure (it need not be measurable itself) then this is *almost* true: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4695123). There is some family of translates whose union's complement has measure zero, so we have "almost" covered all of $\Bbb R$. It follows that if $X$ contains a set of positive measure, there is a null set $N$ such that $X\cup N$ is *not* "smol".

I do not know if literal coverage of all of $\Bbb R$ is possible for arbitrary $X$ of positive measure.

Comment: Fat Cantor sets are meager, so countably many of them can't cover $\mathbb{R}$.